# VBA Explanation: For Loops, Null-Checking and +Cells

Tags: excel, for-loop, null, vba

I have problem with this code:

```
     For i = 18 To 19 + Cells(1, 9)
      If Cells(i,3) = Null Then
        MsgBox "Nie sú zadané všetky vstupné údaje pre príjem za prenájom, doplňte chýbajúce políčka!", vbCritical
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="excel", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        Exit Sub
      End If
     next i
```

I know that this code check cells on null values. However, **what does the first line do**? It is a loop which has steps from 18 to 19, but what does it mean when it says +Cells(1,9)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...what does it mean +Cells(1,9)

The loop will be from `18` to `19 + Cells(1, 9)`. E.g., it's adding the value from `Cells(1, 9)` to `19` to determine when the loop will stop. So if `Cells(1, 9)` contains `3`, for instance, the loop will be from `18` to `22`.

---

**Off-topic**: Are you sure the `If Cells(i,3) = Null` bit works? It's been a long time since I did any VBA, but I thought you had to check for `Null` via `IsNull`, e.g.: `If IsNull(Cells(i,3))`. FWIW.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your note about IsNull. This is not my code, but I have to rewrite it to OpenOffice BASIC. :-<